# IdentityServer4 Signing Certificate Reference tokens

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

Getting errors when an api is trying to validate a reference token.  Our identity server will serve reference tokens only.  Why would a signing certificate be required.   The error is keyset related.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Policy error while contacting the discovery endpoint https://****.net/.well-known/openid-configuration: Keyset is missing
   at IdentityModel.AspNetCore.OAuth2Introspection.PostConfigureOAuth2IntrospectionOptions.GetIntrospectionEndpointFromDiscoveryDocument(OAuth2IntrospectionOptions Options)
   at IdentityModel.AspNetCore.OAuth2Introspection.PostConfigureOAuth2IntrospectionOptions.InitializeIntrospectionClient(OAuth2IntrospectionOptions Options)
   at IdentityModel.AspNetCore.OAuth2Introspection.OAuth2IntrospectionHandler.LoadClaimsForToken(String token)
   at IdentityModel.AspNetCore.OAuth2Introspection.OAuth2IntrospectionHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerAuthenticationHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Ips.Middleware.SerilogMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

Comment: Can you add extra details like the exact error message or exception details and stack trace?

Comment: Added extra information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.  You do not need to make changes to identity.  The changes are to the api.

```
 services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(
    IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, 
    //Null if you do not want to support jwt bearer tokens
    null,
    options =>
    {
      options.Authority = "https://yourIdentityServer.com";
      //This is the key
      options.DiscoveryPolicy.RequireKeySet = false;
      options.ClientId = "xxxx";
      options.ClientSecret = "xxxx";
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the key information being return from the DiscoveryEndpoint by setting `IdentityServerOptions` in IdentityServer:

```
options.Discovery.ShowKeySet = false;
```

Looking the implementation of `PostConfigureOAuth2IntrospectionOptions.InitializeIntrospectionClient`:

```
    private async Task<IntrospectionClient> InitializeIntrospectionClient(OAuth2IntrospectionOptions Options)
    {
        string endpoint;

        if (Options.IntrospectionEndpoint.IsPresent())
        {
            endpoint = Options.IntrospectionEndpoint;
        }
        else
        {
            endpoint = await GetIntrospectionEndpointFromDiscoveryDocument(Options).ConfigureAwait(false);
            Options.IntrospectionEndpoint = endpoint;
        }

        IntrospectionClient client;
        if (Options.IntrospectionHttpHandler != null)
        {
            client = new IntrospectionClient(
                endpoint,
                headerStyle: Options.BasicAuthenticationHeaderStyle,
                innerHttpMessageHandler: Options.IntrospectionHttpHandler);
        }
        else
        {
            client = new IntrospectionClient(endpoint);
        }

        client.Timeout = Options.DiscoveryTimeout;
        return client;
    }
```

You can avoid the call to `GetIntrospectionEndpointFromDiscoveryDocument` by setting the `IntrospectionEndpoint` property on `OAuth2IntrospectionOptions`

Comment: Introspection needs to happen though for reference tokens.

Comment: It doesn't turn off introspection. It only stops configuring the IntrospectionEndpoint from discovery.  Anyway my first suggestion (`options.Discovery.ShowKeySet = false`) should fix your problem properly

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something is validating the discovery document to ensure it’s well formed. You could probably disable this validation by overriding the policy but since you’ll need a signing key for id_tokens anyway you might as well set up the signing and validation credentials.

Comment: Sounds like I'm missing something.  My understanding is that reference tokens are not singed ?

Comment: Indeed not, but the library you’re using is still trying to validate the discovery document. Even if using reference access tokens the id_token will still be a JWT unless I’m very much mistaken.